# Kill the container using systemd API

Tags: podman

I am using PPODMAN systemd based podman containers and to kill the container I just execute the command `systemctl halt` and the container gets killed. I execute following steps:

#### Create Container

```
podman create -t -i \
--restart=always \
--systemd=true \
--name test \
oraclelinux:7 /usr/sbin/init
```

#### Start the Container

```
podman start test
```

#### Kill the container

```
podman exec -i -t test /bin/bash
systemctl halt
```

I want to directly call the system call which basically called by the `systemctl halt` command. How can I call the API using C?

Comment: [systemctl-compat-halt.c](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/5709c7fe4e5c0a5c53b543f3d79cba7fc0ace065/src/systemctl/systemctl-compat-halt.c#L144) on github

Comment: and `halt_now` in [systemctl-util.c](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/ed056c560b47f84a0aa0289151f4ec91f786d24a/src/systemctl/systemctl-util.c)

Comment: and [reboot](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/reboot.2.html)

Comment: Thanks for the input. Is there any in the library to call halt_now from C function?